# Почему загвоздка?

Tags: этимология

Загвоздка — так иначе называют проблему. А при чем тут гвозди, почему именно загвоздка?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что "загвоздить" - вбить гвоздь-остановить топор, причинить препятствие, помеху.

В переносном значении загвоздка- удар кулаком по голове, гвоздить врагов - бить кулаком по голове,ошеломить,как будто вбивать гвоздь в голову, загвоздить память - вот она и помеха.
 Вот в Большом толково-фразеологическом словаре Михельсона:
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/2723/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0